# Ryu OF version error

Tags: sdn, mininet, openflow, ryu

I'm trying to integrate the REST API to a simple switch based on the example in the Ryu book,  here: [chapter 4 here](https://osrg.github.io/ryu-book/en/Ryubook.pdf)

now when I run my code I get an error stating the OF version i'm using isn't supported and breaks at the event `EventOFPHello`. Even though I explicitly set the OF version to 1.3 as required as well as make sure the ports on mininet and ryu are matching!

am I missing something ?

[Here's a screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8YGU5.png) of the error message I'm getting

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I'm not entirely sure if this was causing the problem, but I managed to get it working by updating openvswitch from 1.1 to a newer version (2.3.0)